# Calling a function from a controller in grid

Tags: javascript, function, extjs, controller

I have this code:

```
{
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                dataIndex: 'parentesco',
                itemId: 'parentesco',
                flex: 1,
                text: 'Parentesco',
                editor: {
                        xtype: 'combobox',                            
                        name: 'parientes',
                        valueField: 'codigo',
                        displayField: 'descripcion',
                        store: Ext.create('SgaWeb.store.administrativo.rrhh.dominio.Parentesco', {autoLoad:false}),
                        allowBlank : false,
                        editable: false,
                        //readOnly: true,
                        itemId: 'parientes', 
                        listeners: {
                        beforeselect: function()
                        {
                            var me = this;
                            SgaWeb.app.getController('SgaWeb.controller.administrativo.rrhh.GestionRecursosHumanos').grid();
                            //var gridGrupoFamiliar = me.ventanaGestionRrhh.down('#pestanasVarias').down('#pestanaGrupoFamiliar');
                            var fila = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                            var codigo = fila.get('codigo'); 
                            alert(+codigo);
                        },
                        select: function(combo){                          

                            var id = combo.getValue();
                            var record = combo.getStore().getById(id);
                            record = combo.findRecord(combo.valueField || combo.displayField, id);                                                              

                            me.down('#parentesco').getEditor().setValue(record.get('codigo'));

                            var fila = me.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                            fila.set('parentesco',record.get('codigo'));      

                        },                     
                    }                  
                }         
            },
```

in beforeselect: function, I am trying to call a function from a controller to be triggered before the combobox selection.

is there any way of doing this ?

Comment: What is your extjs version? Your grid (I see a grid column ln your code) has a viewController?

Comment: @josei My extjs version is: Ext JS 4.2.x, and yes it has, I have a view controller where I am trying to call the function, basically I am doing this because I need to get the value of the item selected in my combo box when I am updating a row. I need to set a new value in the combo box depending of the item selected. I have been trying some crazy things but nothing works.

Comment: Ok. The function you want to call is in this controller or is from other componente controller?

Comment: @josei it is in there: SgaWeb.app.getController('SgaWeb.controller.administrativo.rrhh.GestionRecursosHumanos').grid();

Comment: If is in the same controller try this.myfunction(). If is not the same controller try this.getController('controllername').myfunction()